# SXA Creative Exchange Upload Action is failed using gulpBuildMain

Tags: sxa, creative-exchange

I'm working on `Sitecore 10.2` with `SXA`. I'm creating a theme and tried to upload the same using gulp commands like `gulp buildMain` but facing the issue.

```
Status code:500
Answer:<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:pointer; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>Sitecore.Framework.Data.Blobs.Abstractions.BlobProviderException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.<br><br>    

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.                      </code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[BlobProviderException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Sitecore.Framework.Data.Blobs.Azure.TransientHandling.AzureStorageCircuitBreaker.Execute(Action action) +222
   Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.SetBlobStream(Stream stream) +79
   Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaData.SetBlobStream(MediaStream mediaStream) +246
   Sitecore.Resources.Media.Media.SetStream(MediaStream mediaStream) +62
   Spe.sitecore_modules.PowerShell.Services.RemoteScriptCall.ProcessMediaUpload(Stream content, Database db, String path, Boolean skipExisting) +1942
   Spe.sitecore_modules.PowerShell.Services.RemoteScriptCall.ProcessMedia(HttpContext context, Boolean isUpload, Database scriptDb, String itemParam, Boolean unpackZip, Boolean skipExisting) +1364
   Spe.sitecore_modules.PowerShell.Services.RemoteScriptCall.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +4486
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +872
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +220
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +94
</pre>                      </code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4330.0

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!--
[BlobProviderException]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sitecore.Framework.Data.Blobs.Azure.TransientHandling.AzureStorageCircuitBreaker.Execute(Action action)
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.SetBlobStream(Stream stream)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaData.SetBlobStream(MediaStream mediaStream)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Media.Media.SetStream(MediaStream mediaStream)
   at Spe.sitecore_modules.PowerShell.Services.RemoteScriptCall.ProcessMediaUpload(Stream content, Database db, String path, Boolean skipExisting)
   at Spe.sitecore_modules.PowerShell.Services.RemoteScriptCall.ProcessMedia(HttpContext context, Boolean isUpload, Database scriptDb, String itemParam, Boolean unpackZip, Boolean skipExisting)
   at Spe.sitecore_modules.PowerShell.Services.RemoteScriptCall.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is in the logs? There is not enough information here to diagnose what the problem might be.

Comment: if I change anything css, js,  I need to upload the changes into the Sitecore instance using gulp commands. 1. run gulp watchAll command then changed css its should upload the changes.